# How to list users with UIDs higher than 10?

Tags: command-line, users

What commands can I use to display all users who have an identifier (UID) that is greater than 10?

Answer (score 10):

You can parse the [`passwd`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/passwd.5) database using `awk`. In the `passwd` format, each entry is a list of fields delimited by `:`, with the first field being the username and the third field being the UID. So, in awk, you could do:

```
getent passwd | awk -F: '$3 > 10 {print $1}'
```

Comment: You may simply `awk -F ':' '$3 > 10' /etc/passwd` . print is the default behavior, less typing

Comment: @bodhi.zazen as a frequent user of LDAP systems, I see no reason not to use `getent`. And I suppose OP only wants the username.

Comment: through python, `with open(file) as f: for line in f: m = line.split(':'); if int(m[2]) > 10: print(m[0])` . Note that this is not an one-liner.

Answer (score 3):

**SOLUTION 1 :**

You can use:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r line; do
    [[ "$(cut -d: -f3 <<<"$line")" -gt 10 ]] && echo "$line"
done </etc/passwd
```

Considering you have no username containing `:`.

If you just want the usernames:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r line; do
    [[ "$(cut -d: -f3 <<<"$line")" -gt 10 ]] && echo "$(cut -d: -f1 <<<"$line")"
done </etc/passwd
```

Here we are reading each line of the `/etc/passwd` file and comparing the third field delimited by `:` (UID) to check whether it is greater than 10. If it is true, we have printed the line (or username in second script).

This would be much simpler using an array (thanks to muru):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
while IFS=: read -a line; do
    [[ "${line[2]}" -gt 10 ]] && echo "${line[0]}"
done </etc/passwd
```

**SOLUTION 2 :**

Using `grep` with PCRE:

```bsh
getent passwd | grep -P '^[^:]+:[^:]+:(?!(?:\d|10):)' | cut -d: -f1
```

- `^[^:]+:` will match the first field (username) including trailing `:`
- `[^:]+:` will match the second field (password) including trailing `:`
- `(?!(?:\d|10):)` part is tricky, it is a zero width negative lookahead patern of PCRE (`grep -P`), it means there is no single digit (`\d`) number or number 10 next, followed by a `:`.
- `cut -d: -f1` will just print the first field (username).

Alternately, you can avoid the `cut`, by using the negative lookahead `(?!)` inside of the positive lookahead `(?=)` pattern (thanks to Avinash Raj) :

```
getent passwd | grep -Po '^[^:]+(?=:[^:]+:(?!(?:\d|10):))'
```

**SOLUTION 3 :**

using `python` :

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python2
with open('/etc/passwd') as f:
    print '\n'.join([line.split(':')[0] for line in f if int(line.split(':')[2]) > 10])
```

Here we are printing usernames if the third field is grater than 10. `line.split(':')` will split fields of each line on `:`, making it a list of fields.

Comment: Set  `IFS=:`, and use `read -a`, then you can use `${line[0]}` and `${line[2]}` directly.

Comment: @muru thank you very much..i have not thought it that way..adding..

Comment: @heemayl i think you may try `^[^:]+(?=:[^:]+:(?!(?:\d|10):))`, you don't need for `cut` command.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Thank you very much..neat..added..

Answer (score 1):

Using awk:

```
 awk -F: '{if ($3 > 10) { print $1 ":" $3 } }' /etc/passwd
```

this will list all users with their associated UID where UID > 10.

Thanks to @sadi note, to list only usernames

```
awk -F: '{if ($3 > 10) {print $1}}' /etc/passwd
```

Comment: This lists all usernames followed by a column and UID. However this lists **usernames only**: `awk -F: '{if ($3 > 10) {print $1}}' /etc/passwd`

Comment: @Sadi thanks but I insert the UID to show each User  with its associated UID

Comment: I understand; I just wanted to add a note how to modify this in case only usernames are required - UpVoted ;-)